# How to edit a html template so that it shows a different logo for each company?

Tags: html, css

I assumed it wouldn't be too difficult so jumped on the wagon to try to send automated email templates.

We send these emails to around 8 different categories/companies. I want the recipient company's logo on the up left side of the page.

For each company, the template must understand which company is it for and create the logo accordingly. Currently it is our own fixed logo on this left side.

How can I do that?

```html
<body>
    <font face="Arial" Font-Size=10pt>
    
    <table border="0"  width="720" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" id="table6">
      <tr>
        <td width="336">
          <font face="Arial" Font-Size=10pt>
            <a href="http://www...ourwebsite...net">
              <img border="0" src="OurLogo.gif" width="335" height="96">
            </a>
          </font>
        </td>
        <td width="340">
          &nbsp;
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>
            <font face="Arial" Font-Size=10pt>
              <b><font face="Arial" font-size=14pt>SOME TITLE</font> </b>
            </font>
        </td>
        <td width="88">
          <p align="right">
            <font face="Arial" Font-Size=10pt>
              <img border="0" src="Another_Random_Logo.gif" width="73" height="45" align="right">
            </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: How do you send your emails?  Ideally you'd need to pass the data (e.g. the company logo) into a template file from your backend (e.g. PHP) before the email is sent.

Comment: Your html is having few errors, `p` tag not closed  2 times as a start. I guess it is because you were trying to reduce code for example. You should try to make a reproduicible example

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this:

1. Created an array of images.
2. Added `onclick` on select. Upon your selection the `changeCompany` function will be called and an image from the array will be selected  based on the index.

```js
let images = ['https://i.picsum.photos/id/0/367/267.jpg?hmac=7vvdjNHaShwe3Ul3DAaQIBBz0RnNLfUcEaCV-94NNLE', 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/1001/367/267.jpg?hmac=h9_xzQEoMCgh9gDWOgnNnsEC9eTnf3j2BTfKXt8uu6U', 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/367/267.jpg?hmac=mNdSdA1Zh6w4qessdp5n207IFw3q_8FbbQ1gIr0jYBs'];

function changeCompany(id) {
    document.getElementById("company_image").src = images[id];
  console.log(images[id])
}
```

```html
<div id="custom_select" style="width:200px;">
  <select onclick="changeCompany(value)">
    <option value="0">Company 1</option>
    <option value="1">Company 2</option>
    <option value="2">Company 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<img id="company_image" src="">
```

[Working **JsFiddle code**](https://jsfiddle.net/bru4L8fe/)